# PDO define() access denied

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to connect using PDO but I am receiving the following error

```
'Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

this is my user class:

```
include "db_config.php";

class User
{

    //object variables
    public $pdo;
    public $user_data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_DATABASE, //DSN
            DB_USERNAME, //Username
            DB_PASSWORD //Password
    );
```

db_config.php:

```
//the address for the database server
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');

//the username for the database server
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');

//the password for the database server
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

//name of the databse
define('DB_DATABASE', 'cfs-ex');
```

Not too sure what I am missing out if I replace DB_PASSWORD with 'root' it works fine so I don't think there is anything wrong with the database itself or with the password

Comment: Do a `var_dump(DB_PASSWORD);` as the first statement in your constructor. See if it contains the expected value. If not, then maybe it's being overridden somewhere else.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Constants can't be redefined in PHP. My guess is that he's not actually loading the `db_config.php` he thinks he is.

Comment: @RoAchterberg using var dump shows DB_PASSWORD as "" however the other constants all return their true values. Using sublime text I searched the whole project for DB_PASSWORD and it returns this. https://imgur.com/a/o7BuZr6

Comment: @Rajbir ..so the true(as in "what it actually is defined as") value of DB_PASSWORD is displayed too :)? The `using password: NO` part in the error message might be a hint too.

Comment: ok this is really dumb but turns out, there were 2 db_config.php files one with the password one without, the one that I was viewing had the password, the one that was linked was the one with the empty field

Comment: Ok, good to hear it's working now. Consider defining an absolute root path as a prefix to all your includes; this way there is never any confusion as to which path the `include()` is relative to.